# How to get only current date?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want only date not time from the string value.

```
Protected Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
 Dim d As String=3/31/2014 12:00:00 AM
 Dim str() As String = d.Split("")
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you've given isn't even valid code, and we have no idea where the input is coming from. Ideally, you should avoid the string conversion entirely in your code, using an appropriate control which handles it all for you. That's if it's user input, of course - you haven't explained the situation. If you actually want the *current* time, then `DateTime.Today` is appropriate, but then why do you have a string at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After slight changes in your code, I was able to extract date part.

```
Imports System

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
         Dim d As String= "3/31/2014 12:00:00 AM"
         Dim str() As String = d.Split(" ")

         Console.WriteLine(str(0))
             ' 3/31/2014     <----- this is the output
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you are bothered about insertion of date in database then you should look at date function of your database. e.g., SQL Server gives [functions to get current date and format it](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime.Today property. It will return date component of DateTime.Now. It is equivalent of DateTime.Now.Date.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;              // Use current time
string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";    // Use this format
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));  // Write to console
```

Comment: but it does store in data base in the format "3/31/2014 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: use this format... hope this could help

Comment: I guess this should be the accepted answer. As far as I know, you cannot remove the `time` part of the `DateTime` datatype from a database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Dim dt as new Date
dt=now()
If CDate(dt) Then
    dim str as string=Format(dt,"dd/MM/yyyy")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()
```